# Calling Twitter Streaming API (statuses/filter) from vb.net webpage

Tags: vb.net, api, twitter, streaming

I am trying to call Streaming API filter inside my .net webpage.

I did create an app on twitter and took the credentials needed(consumer key,consumer secret,access token and access token secret)

This is the code am using

```
 Public Function StreamAPI()
    Dim url As String = "https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json?track=example.com/example"


    Dim oauthconsumerkey As String = "consumerkey"
    Dim oauthconsumersecret As String = "consumersecret"
    Dim oauthsignaturemethod As String = "HMAC-SHA1"
    Dim oauthversion As String = "1.0"
    Dim oauthtoken As String = "token"
    Dim oauthtokensecret As String = "tokenkey"

    Dim oauthnonce As String = Convert.ToBase64String(New ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()))
    Dim timeSpan As TimeSpan = DateTime.UtcNow - New DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, _
        0, DateTimeKind.Utc)
    Dim oauthtimestamp As String = Convert.ToInt64(timeSpan.TotalSeconds).ToString()
    Dim basestringParameters As New SortedDictionary(Of String, String)()
    basestringParameters.Add("track", "example.com/example")
    basestringParameters.Add("oauth_version", oauthversion)
    basestringParameters.Add("oauth_consumer_key", oauthconsumerkey)
    basestringParameters.Add("oauth_nonce", oauthnonce)
    basestringParameters.Add("oauth_signature_method", oauthsignaturemethod)
    basestringParameters.Add("oauth_timestamp", oauthtimestamp)
    basestringParameters.Add("oauth_token", oauthtoken)

    Dim baseString As New StringBuilder()
    baseString.Append("GET" + "&")
    baseString.Append(EncodeCharacters(Uri.EscapeDataString(url.Split("?"c)(0)) + "&"))
    For Each entry As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In basestringParameters
        baseString.Append(EncodeCharacters(Uri.EscapeDataString(entry.Key + "=" + entry.Value + "&")))
    Next


    Dim finalBaseString As String = baseString.ToString().Substring(0, baseString.Length - 3)


    Dim signingKey As String = EncodeCharacters(Uri.EscapeDataString(oauthconsumersecret)) + "&" + EncodeCharacters(Uri.EscapeDataString(oauthtokensecret))

    'Sign the request
    Dim hasher As New HMACSHA1(New ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(signingKey))
    Dim oauthsignature As String = Convert.ToBase64String(hasher.ComputeHash(New ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(finalBaseString)))


    Dim webRequest__1 As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
    Dim authorizationHeaderParams As New StringBuilder()
    authorizationHeaderParams.Append("OAuth ")
    authorizationHeaderParams.Append("oauth_nonce=" + """" + Uri.EscapeDataString(oauthnonce) + """,")
    authorizationHeaderParams.Append("oauth_signature_method=" + """" + Uri.EscapeDataString(oauthsignaturemethod) + """,")
    authorizationHeaderParams.Append("oauth_timestamp=" + """" + Uri.EscapeDataString(oauthtimestamp) + """,")
    authorizationHeaderParams.Append("oauth_consumer_key=" + """" + Uri.EscapeDataString(oauthconsumerkey) + """,")
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(oauthtoken) Then
        authorizationHeaderParams.Append("oauth_token=" + """" + Uri.EscapeDataString(oauthtoken) + """,")
    End If
    authorizationHeaderParams.Append("oauth_signature=" + """" + Uri.EscapeDataString(oauthsignature) + """,")
    authorizationHeaderParams.Append("oauth_version=" + """" + Uri.EscapeDataString(oauthversion) + """")
    webRequest__1.Headers.Add("Authorization", authorizationHeaderParams.ToString)

    webRequest__1.Method = "GET"
    webRequest__1.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

    webRequest__1.Timeout = 3 * 60 * 1000
    Try

        Dim webResponse As HttpWebResponse = TryCast(webRequest__1.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

        Dim dataStream As System.IO.Stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream()
        ' Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
        ' Read the content.
        Dim responseFromServer As String
        responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd()
        Return responseFromServer
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

End Function
```

The function doesnt return anything. At row containing`reader.ReadToEnd()` in debug mode it is showing "Unable to evaluate expression".

The same code works correctly if the url is in this format
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/application/rate_limit_status.json
or 
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=example

Any reason why it doesn't work for stream apis? I cant use search api since it doesn't return all results I need, for example tweets containing urls are not returned by search api.

I did try tweetinvi library for .net projects as suggested by twitter website.

```
Public Sub Twit()
    Dim oauthconsumerkey As String = "consumerkey"
    Dim oauthconsumersecret As String = "consumersecret"
    Dim oauthsignaturemethod As String = "HMAC-SHA1"
    Dim oauthversion As String = "1.0"
    Dim oauthtoken As String = "token"
    Dim oauthtokensecret As String = "tokensecret"

    Auth.SetUserCredentials(oauthconsumerkey, oauthconsumersecret, oauthtoken, oauthtokensecret)
    Auth.ApplicationCredentials = New TwitterCredentials(oauthconsumerkey, oauthconsumersecret, oauthtoken, oauthtokensecret)

    Dim filteredStream = Tweetinvi.Stream.CreateFilteredStream()
    filteredStream.AddTrack("example")
    Dim txt As String = ""


    AddHandler filteredStream.MatchingTweetReceived, Sub(sender As Object, args As Tweetinvi.Core.Events.EventArguments.MatchedTweetReceivedEventArgs)
                                                         Console.WriteLine(args.Tweet.Text)
                                                         txt &= args.Tweet.Text
                                                     End Sub

    filteredStream.StartStreamMatchingAllConditions()

End Sub
```

But this is not returning anything. The event is not getting called and i am not getting any result.

Both methods failed.Is there any other clear example that I can use to call statuses/filter from vb.net webpages?

Answer (score 0):

I am the developer of Tweetinvi.

Your code looks correct. Would you please let me know what exception you receive.

Also, I am not sure to understand if this code is invoked directly in the page (I am not familiar with WebForms), but please not that `StartStreamMatchingAllConditions` will be blocking the `Thread` it runs in until the stream stop.

If you want this to be running behind the scene you will want to use the `async` version : `StartStreamMatchingAllConditionsAsync()`.

Finally, the way I send stream tweets to a UI is by using WebSocket and send information from the server to a javascript handler.

Comment: Using Twetinvi am not getting any exceptions , the code just doesnt do anything. I did add async function but still the same. This function is getting called on page_load in a webpage. Can you plz provide a coded example how to get the strean tweets in order to check and loop over them?

Comment: I will take a look, I know I have and example somewhere.